# Can a Symfony controller return multiple Responses at the same time in the same method?

Tags: symfony

So I made a controller with a code that gets multiple objects from an entity (let's call it "Book") and returns a Response object with an array version of that Book in json. After calling this request, my server crashed and I got a 502 "Bad Gateway" response for my whole symfony app. Is it possible that symfony doesn't allow multiple Response objects for the same request? Did the server crash because of this? Thanks in advance. I'll leave the code below:

```
/**
 * @Route("/getallbooks")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAllBooks()
{
    $allBooks = $this->em->getRepository(Book::class)->findAll();
    foreach ($allBooks as $book){
        return new Response(json_encode($book->toArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can't return multiple responses for a single request.
Return a single response with all books in an `array` instead.

```
$allBooks = $this->em->getRepository(Book::class)->findAll(); 
$data = array_map(function($book) { return $book->toArray(); }, $allBooks);
return new Response(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function and returns its argument as the value of the function call...
> From [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

After your first return, the loop and function execution ends.

Try this

```
/**
 * @Route("/getallbooks")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAllBooks()
{
    $allBooks = $this->em->getRepository(Book::class)->findAll();
    $response = [];
    foreach ($allBooks as $book){
        $response[] = array(
            'id' => $book->getId()
            //add here other info
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse(  $response);
}
```

Response

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12},{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15},{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18},{"id":19},{"id":20},{"id":21},{"id":22},{"id":23},{"id":24},{"id":25},{"id":26}]
```